# Fetching registry keys in root of HKEY Constants

Tags: python, python-3.x, registry

There's seems to be no way to access HKEY Constants' root with `winreg.OpenKey`.

With absolute minimum:

```py
>>> import winreg
>>> target_root = winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
>>> h_key = winreg.OpenKey(target_root, "")
>>> out = winreg.EnumValue(h_key, 0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: [WinError 259] 사용 가능한 데이터가 없습니다  # No usable data

>>> out = winreg.EnumKey(h_key, 0)
>>> out
'BCD00000000'
>>> winreg.OpenKey(h_key, out)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
PermissionError: [WinError 5] 액세스가 거부되었습니다  # Access denied
```

With this example code:

```py
import winreg
import itertools


root = ""
target_root = winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
h_key = winreg.OpenKey(target_root, root)


def iterkeys(key):
    """
    Recursively iterates thru keys, revealing all keys.
    returns absolute path relative to root, and EnumValue result.
    """

    for i in itertools.count():
        try:
            out = winreg.EnumValue(key, i)
        except OSError as err:
            try:
                out = winreg.EnumKey(key, i)
            except OSError as err:  # end of key
                return

            # else it's likely to be a folder. recursively opens it.
            try:
                yield from iterkeys(winreg.OpenKey(key, out))
            except OSError as err_:
                return

        else:
            yield out


print(f"Registry found: {len(list(iterkeys(h_key)))}")
```

---

I would get proper registry counts when specifying any folder.

```
# with root="SOFTWARE"
Registry found: 189845
```

However, it shows weird results when leaving it blank, so I could - I believe - access top node of the tree.

```
# with root=""
Registry found: 0
```

Normally if there's no such path then `winreg.OpenKey` would raises `OSError`, but this is not even that case.

Not even official document has much to tell about accessing top node of registry tree, is there any workaround for this?

---

If you need context why this is needed, I recently changed User folder name as MS forcefully named it in non-Latin letters, so I needed tons of registry editing.
[Full code](https://github.com/jupiterbjy/PersonalToolkit/blob/main/Other%20Tools/RegistryUpdateUser.py) here if needed.

Comment: Did you print the error within the try block of `yield from iterkeys(winreg.OpenKey(key, out))`?

Comment: Forgot to mention it. It just says Access denied. As this script converted around 100 entries successfully I don't think this has nothing to do with admin privilege.

Comment: It seems like some of the folders(for example [this](https://renenyffenegger.ch/notes/Windows/registry/tree/HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/BCD00000000/index)) will result in "Access denied." I think you also need to handle a condition to skip over the keys which shows the  permission error. I also think that `OpenKey` here is working as expected.

Comment: Without these recursive scripts, mere 7 lines in Console is enough to reproduce it, it's not recursion problem, as this will skip any winreg related issues and keep on. I'll update with even smaller example.